# PowerPoint 2016 VBA: Line Spacing (Single) and Before and After = 0

Tags: vba, line, powerpoint, spacing

I would like a VBA script that does the following:

1. Changes all slide Line Spacing to **Single**
2. Changes all slide Spacing Before and After to **0**

My research online so far hasn't been successful and any test runs have come back with errors.

Comment: We can't help you fix the problems with your existing code unless you show us what you have so far and tell us where it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution that doesn't require VBA/Macros. If using PowerPoint 2016, under the View tab, choose Outline View. Here you can select all the slides with Ctrl + A, and now go to Home, click the small arrow in the Paragraph section and you can change the settings for all slides there. You must be in Outline View mode to do this as otherwise, PowerPoint won't let you change paragraph settings for more than one slide at a time.

Comment: That'll only affect the text in placeholders, not other text on the slide. If that's sufficient, then problem solved.